# How to use Android UWB API in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, uwb

I'm trying to implement an UWB ranging app for Android in java. However, the the UWB API seems to be Kotlin only and I have a hard time integrating it into my existing java code.

The UWB API seems to be pretty straight forward (see [Android UWB Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/uwb#sample_app)):

1. get ranging parameters
2. create sessionScope
3. start ranging

However, when using Java, I fail at step 2. What I've tried is:

```
UwbManager uwbManager = UwbManager.createInstance(context);
UwbControllerSessionScope uwbControllerSessionScope = (UwbControllerSessionScope) uwbManager.controllerSessionScope();
```

which doas not compile because `uwbManager.controllerSessionScope()` actually requires some `Continuation` object as a parameter. Then I tried to pass an anonymous Continuation object (altough I have no idea whether this code makes any sense, but thats a different problem):

```
UwbManager uwbManager = UwbManager.createInstance(context);
               UwbControllerSessionScope uwbControllerSessionScope = (UwbControllerSessionScope) uwbManager.controllerSessionScope(new Continuation<UwbControllerSessionScope>() {
                   @NonNull
                   @Override
                   public CoroutineContext getContext() {
                       return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;     //what does this mean?
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void resumeWith(@NonNull Object o) {
                       //TODO ???
                   }
               });
```

Now, the app crashes because `uwbManager.controllerSessionScope()` does not return a `UwbControllerSessionScope` object, but instead a `kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.CoroutineSingletons``object. At this point, it seems to me that the UWB feature is not compatible with java. Am I missing something?

I know that Android UWB is still in alpha, but it still appears odd to me that it is only supported by Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on Integrating the UWB into Android. For that, I created the library in Java.OOB mechanisms based on Ble to exchange the BLE required Ranging parameters.

Link: https://github.com/ajayvamsee/Uwb-Library

Under the **uwbControl** package: UwbRangingController.java is the main file to start Ranging like the base class to use the library.

Under **manager** package: UwbManagerHelper.java have core uses of UWB API in Android. Go through this class you will get our solution.

**Dependencies:**

```
implementation "androidx.core.uwb:uwb-rxjava3:1.0.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.core.uwb:uwb:1.0.0-alpha04"
```